# Is there an English translation version for Weber's classic paper "Zum Zerfall eines Flüssigkeitsstrahles"?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, specific-reference

I think the title would be "The disintegration of a liquid sheet" or something.

Maybe an old NACA report?

Ref: Weber, Constantin. "Zum zerfall eines flüssigkeitsstrahles." ZAMM‐Journal of Applied Mathematics and Mechanics/Zeitschrift für Angewandte Mathematik und Mechanik 11, no. 2 (1931): 136-154.

Comment: it seems it has been translated for oak ridge  , see this search https://books.google.gr/books?id=ip0sLnmPlBQC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=Zum+Zerfall+eines+Fl%C3%BCssigkeitsstrahles+translation+oakridge&source=bl&ots=RWm-ntFN3x&sig=ACfU3U3DQesJGba_CuP6oIAWeoNitwXjJw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS38Gw65LjAhUIYlAKHdpfBd8Q6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Zum%20Zerfall%20eines%20Fl%C3%BCssigkeitsstrahles%20translation%20oakridge&f=false

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am looking for. But it seems difficult to find this report copy on the internet...

Comment: You could find someone to translate it ... and pay... if it is that important.

Comment: Disintegration of a fluid jet

Comment: you should contact the library at Oakridge national labratory https://www.ornl.gov/content/research-library . Maybe if you are a student they would help with a photocopy

Comment: Unfortunately it is not available at the Oakridge national laboratory any more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I typed up a [University of Colorado Boulder translation](https://www.worldcat.org/title/on-the-breakdown-of-a-fluid-jet/oclc/18571823) (apparently funded by the US military) that's older and much better than the mentioned Oak Ridge translation. I also made a fair number of improvements and corrections.

The translation is available at my university's repository here: http://dx.doi.org/10.26153/tsw/3371

The Oak Ridge translation has almost no equations printed in it and is fairly rough. It is available at the Library of Congress [TRS unit](https://www.loc.gov/rr/scitech/trs/trsover.html) in microfilm, report no. AEC-TR-3783.

I'd recommend reading a paper like [Sterling and Sleicher's](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/instability-of-capillary-jets/E6B50511B8BEECD9C95301B9B834F230) if you want a similar result using more modern methods and notation.

Finally, I wrote an answer on Academia Stack Exchange on [how to locate translations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/93209/31143) that may be of interest. Through one of the translation indices I mention I read about [another English translation of this paper at the British Library](http://explore.bl.uk/BLVU1:LSCOP-ALL:BLL01018516791) which I don't have a copy of.